# Primality of $\ \frac{b^p-a^p}{b-a}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Can you prove the following:

**Conjecture:**  Let $\ p\in\mathbb P\ $ be an arbitrary prime. Then there exist two relatively prime integers $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ such that $\ a>0\ $ and $\ b>1\ $ and

$$ \frac{b^p-a^p}{b-a} \in\ \mathbb P. $$

=================================================================

A harder question would be a restriction to $\ b=a+1.$

See also the comment below by @GHfromMO.

==================================================================

Finally, one may ask the same question about
$\ 2\, <\, p\, \in\,\mathbb P\ $ but for:

$$ \frac {a^p+b^p}{a+b}. $$

Comment: Would you add some context? Is this a conjecture found somewhere, or a conjecture you formulated? Are you asking whether this is true, or whether this is known (as a conjecture)?

Comment: @YCor, yes, I've formulated it. #### No, I never saw it anywhere at any time; this conjecture is so simple that there is a good chance that I was not the first.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger, "Conjecture" is a synonym of "question" (while "conjecture" is more specific than a general "question"). #### The question is: can you prove it?

Comment: @YCor, the word "conjecture" is both a guess and a question about the validity of the guess.

Comment: Up to which number have you checked the conjecture?

Comment: The conjecture is a special case (or weaker version) of Bunyakovsky's conjecture: there should be infinitely many solutions even with $a=1$ (for any given $p$). I am certain that even this special case (or weaker version) is out of reach. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture#Cyclotomic_polynomials

Comment: @GHfromMO, thank you.